# Check mailbox via Microsoft Graph

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

My customer is using the PowerShell cmdlet "Get Recipient" to check, if during the provisioning of the user the mailbox was enabled (Sometimes this dont work).
Output of "get-recipient" is "RecipientType" -> Mailuser or Usermailbox.

We want to get the same output with graph explorer. 
1.  Does anybody know the right query for that in graph?
2.  I tried it with that query: user@customer.de/mailboxSettings">https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@customer.de/mailboxSettings
•   I receive an error message that my credentials are invalid.
•   Im using my global admin, the necessary scopes are granted (verified on the service principal in azure ad. "Read and write user mailbox settings, Delegated, Admin consent")

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_update_mailboxsettings

BR Thomas

Answer (score 2):

If you want to query the user with the mailbox in Microsoft graph explorer, the only way is what you tried by the mailboxsettings. 
[image]
And the required permission is:
[image]

Comment: Hi, my users has this permissions, thats the strange thing here (as described i can also see the permissions on Microsoft graph service principal in azure ad). May you can test this in your lab if it´s the same behavior?

Comment: I tried on my side, if the account has no Microsoft O365 subscription, it will prompt error of invalid credential.

Comment: cool thx. now it works. But unfortunately, nothing from that output helps to detect the difference if its "mailuser" or "usermailbox". Do you see any chance to get this information via graph?

Comment: Because this operation is related to the Microsoft Office 365, I think you could try to get further help from the Microsoft O365.

Comment: @Thomas，I already discussed this issue with our O365 team, the Microsoft Graph Explorer cannot get mailuser or usermailbox claim in the user properties. But you could use [JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_6/office.recipients?view=office-js) of Office to get this.